# How to customize/theme contact_form module in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-theming, drupal-8, drupal-forms

I created my custom module(contact_form) but I don't know How to theme this form? How to create a template or how to add CSS in my form?
I have my CSS and JS.

Answer (score 0):

can you check drupal.com documentation :https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

> The general steps for loading assets (CSS/JS) are:
>
> ```
> 1. Save the CSS or JS to a file.
> 2. Define a "library", which can contain both CSS and JS files.
> 3. "Attach" the library to a render array in a hook.
> ```
>
> But in the case of themes, there is an alternative to step 3: themes
>   can choose to load any number of asset libraries on all pages.

check this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37723273/1153703

you can also check the costume theme example I fount here : http://wiki.workassis.com/drupal-8-custom-theme-from-scratch/